# suppress the 'labelled' from class()

Tags: r

This is with regard to the dataframe 'have' as created below, in this i derived a variable name with a label. so i get the have dataframe with variable name and a label. when i check the class of the variable in the have dataframe i also see the 'labelled' which i dont want to see i only want see the 'character', so please let me know is there a way i apply the label as well but when i use the class then i see only see 'character'

```r
# creating a data frame have
have <- data.frame(name=c('person1','person2','person3','person4'))
# applying a label to the data frame
label(have$name) <- 'Name of person'
# checking the class of the variable within the dataframe
class(have$name)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove the label? Because you can't really have a functioning label without also having the "labelled" class. The class gives the object it's behavior. If you change the class, you change the behavior.

Comment: is there a way to apply the label as well without affecting the class, I need the label displayed.

Comment: Not really. What exactly do you need? Why is having the extra class a problem? Where do you need to see the labels? And just to be clear, what package does your `label` function come from since that's not a base R function.

Comment: Try to understand the purpose of `class` versus `attributes` versus `typeof`, there is really no need to remove any class values. If you want to see that `have$name` is of type `character` then use simply `typeof(have$name)` which will output `[1] "character"`